# Retrieve and show DATA FORMS (GET) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a first page, which, onload, shows the default get params.

**Page1.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="assets/main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body">
    <div>
        <h1>Nous avons reçu : </h1>
        <h2 style="display: inline-block">LOGIN : </h2>
        <p style="display: inline-block" id="login"></p>
    </div>
    <div >
        <h2 style="display: inline-block">PASSWORD : </h2>
        <p style="display: inline-block" id="password"></p>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

**Page1_main.js**

```
// Version 1


const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const params = url.searchParams;


params.set('LOGIN', 'Licois');
params.append('PASSWORD', 'Johanne')


url.search = params.toString();
window.history.replaceState({}, '', location.pathname + '?' + params);


if (params.has('LOGIN')) {
    alert("Licois !");
} else {
    alert("Licois est introuvable !")
}

if (params.has('PASSWORD')) {
    alert("Johanne !");
} else {
    alert("Johanne a disparu !")
}
    
document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = params.get("LOGIN");
document.getElementById("password").textContent = params.get("PASSWORD");
```

Result : [page1 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Ao1.png)

Ok, this is what I wanted.
But then, I have to have another page (with html only), which will send new get parametes to the first page, and shown them there in the HTML and URL. But in this case I cannot show "Joanne" and "Licois" anymore, or show the new params as "param3= " and "param4= ".

**Page2_html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exercice 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Page1.html" method="GET">
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" >
        <div><br></div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" type="password" for="password" name="password" id="password">
        <div><br></div>
        <button type="submit" id="envoyer">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Page2_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HenJ8.png)

I succeed at sending the new params to the first page ("action='Page1.html'").
But I can't manage to show them in the HTML and URL.

Answer (score 0):

No, nevermind, I got it.

Changed Page2.html to

```
<body>
    <form action="Page1.html" method="GET">
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="NEW_LOGIN" id="NEW_LOGIN" >
        <div><br></div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" type="password" for="password" name="NEW_PASSWORD" id="NEW_PASSWORD">
        <div><br></div>
        <button type="submit" id="envoyer">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

And added this to Page1_main.js

```
if (params.has('NEW_LOGIN')) {
    document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = params.get("NEW_LOGIN");
} else if ((params.has('LOGIN'))) {
    document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = params.get("LOGIN");
}

if (params.has('NEW_PASSWORD')) {
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = params.get("NEW_PASSWORD");
} else if ((params.has('PASSWORD'))) {
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = params.get("PASSWORD");
}
```

EZ